# how to use the checkbox to append a string into an arrey?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, checkbox

I have 3 checkbox created in a html file next to a text input. I am trying to get the input values appended to an empty array if the input box is checked. how should i do that? thank you

```
question = document.getElementById("question").value;
result1 = document.getElementById("result1").value;
result2 = document.getElementById("result2").value;
result3 = document.getElementById("result3").value;
correctRes1 = document.getElementById("check1");
correctRes2 = document.getElementById("check2");
correctRes3 = document.getElementById("check3");
correct = [];

function check() {
if (correctRes1.checked == true) {
  correct.push(result1);
}
if (correctRes2.checked == true) {
  correct.push(result1);
}
if (correctRes3.checked == true) {
  correct.push(result3);
}
}

raw = JSON.stringify({
question: question,
answer: [result1, result2, result3],
correctAns: correct,
});
console.log(raw)
```

the code above is not working. its not appending when I am calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
question = document.getElementById("question").value;
result1 = document.getElementById("result1").value;
result2 = document.getElementById("result2").value;
result3 = document.getElementById("result3").value;
correctRes1 = document.getElementById("check1");
correctRes2 = document.getElementById("check2");
correctRes3 = document.getElementById("check3");
correct = [];

document.getElementById('do-check-btn').addEventListener('click',doCheck);

function check() {
if (correctRes1.checked == true) {
  correct.push(result1);
}
if (correctRes2.checked == true) {
  correct.push(result1);
}
if (correctRes3.checked == true) {
  correct.push(result3);
}
}


function doCheck(){
  check();
  raw = JSON.stringify({
  question: question,
  answer: [result1, result2, result3],
  correctAns: correct,
  });
  document.getElementById("pre-out").innerHTML = raw;

}
```

```html
<textarea id="question">Here be the question</textarea>
<div><input type="text" id="result1" value="Here be dragons"/><input type="checkbox" id="check1" /></div>
<div><input type="text" id="result2" value="Here be ghosts"/><input type="checkbox" id="check2" /></div>
<div><input type="text" id="result3" value="Here be pirates"/><input type="checkbox" id="check3" /></div>

<button id="do-check-btn">Do Check</button>

<pre id="pre-out"></pre>
```

I've added your code to a button event. See if you can get this to work with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost right.  The only problem is that the code is only being run once when you load the page.

You need to [add event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) to run the code each time there is a change with your input checkboxes.